# Spring JPA Query to return List of objects and count from join table

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have been trying to write a query that will return a specific entity class aswell as the entity's id count from a joining table.

I have two entity classes: one Component class and another which is a 'subcomponent' of this class called ComponentVersion. A Component can have many ComponentVersions and are associated by componentid.

**Component.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="component")
public class Component {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "componenttabid")
    private int componenttabid;

    @Column(name = "componentid")
    private String componentid;

    @Column(name = "componentname")
    private String componentname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "component", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ComponentVersion> componentversions;

    public Component() {
    }

    public Component(int componenttabid, String componentid, String componentname) {
        this.componenttabid = componenttabid;
        this.componentid = componentid;
        this.componentname = componentname;
    }

    public Component(int componenttabid, String componentid, String componentname,
            List<ComponentVersion> componentversions) {
        this.componenttabid = componenttabid;
        this.componentid = componentid;
        this.componentname = componentname;
        this.componentversions = componentversions;
    }

    //getters and setters

}
```

**ComponentVersion.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="component_version")
public class ComponentVersion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name= "componentversionid")
    private int componentversionid;

    @Column(name= "componentid")
    private String componentid;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Component.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "componentid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Component component;

    @Column(name= "version")
    private String version;

    @Column(name= "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name= "statuschangedate")
    private LocalDateTime statuschangedate;

    @Column(name= "componentdescription")
    private String componentdescription;
    
    @Column(name = "componenturl")
    private String componenturl;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "component_scan", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "componentversionid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "scanid"))
    private List<Scan> scans;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "component", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ComponentServerModification> componentServerModifications;

    public ComponentVersion() {
    }

    public ComponentVersion(int componentversionid, String componentid, String version, String status,
            LocalDateTime statuschangedate, String componentdescription, String componenturl) {
        this.componentversionid = componentversionid;
        this.componentid = componentid;
        this.version = version;
        this.status = status;
        this.statuschangedate = statuschangedate;
        this.componentdescription = componentdescription;
        this.componenturl = componenturl;
    }

    //getters and setters
    
}
```

I have created this custom object class to help map the return value. The component variable represents the component object and the versionCount variable represents the number of times the component's id appears within the ComponentVersion table.

**ComponentAndVersionCountResponse.java**

```
public class ComponentAndVersionCountResponse {

    private Component component;

    private Long versionCount;

    public ComponentAndVersionCountResponse(Component component, Long versionCount) {
        this.component = component;
        this.versionCount = versionCount;
    }

//getters and setters
```

I have tried using the following JPA Query but have had no success:

```
public interface ComponentRepository extends JpaRepository<Component, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.tool.modifiedcomponenttool.payload.response.ComponentAndVersionCountResponse(x, COUNT(z.componentid)) FROM Component x JOIN x.componentversions z GROUP By z.componentid")
    public List<ComponentAndVersionCountResponse> findComponentAndVersionCount();
}
```

I am prompted with the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 234
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114) ~[postgresql-42.2.23.jar:42.2.23]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2297) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2843) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2825) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2657) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1636) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.findComponentAndVersionCount(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.tool.modifiedcomponenttool.controller.ComponentController.getAllComponentsIdWithScan(ComponentController.java:72) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at com.tool.modifiedcomponenttool.configuration.JwtTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtTokenFilter.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

**Error when trying**

@Query("SELECT x, COUNT(z.componentid) FROM Component x JOIN x.componentversions z GROUP By z.componentid")

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'componentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'componentService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'componentService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'componentVersionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'componentVersionRepository' defined in com.tool.modifiedcomponenttool.repository.ComponentVersionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.tool.modifiedcomponenttool.repository.ComponentVersionRepository.getComponentAndNoOfVersions()! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.tool.modifiedcomponenttool.repository.ComponentVersionRepository.getComponentAndNoOfVersions()!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.tool.modifiedcomponenttool.repository.ComponentVersionRepository.getComponentAndNoOfVersions()!
```

Been stuck on this one for a while now...Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How you tried @Query("SELECT x, COUNT(z.componentid) FROM Component x JOIN x.componentversions z GROUP By z.componentid") ?

Comment: @semiColon yes I have also tried that with no success. In fact when I run that query my Spring application wont even start. According to the error message it is due to failed validation. I have updated the post so you can see the message in full. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you put a breakpoint at `processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)` and debug to see what is the type you're getting.

Comment: You could also try it with a native query? @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="your sql here")

Answer (score 0):

Change the **componentID column data type** to int in both component.java and ComponentVersion.java as you are querying to count the string values through JPA.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="component")
public class Component {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "componenttabid")
    private int componenttabid;

    @Column(name = "componentid")
    private int componentid; 

    @Column(name = "componentname")
    private String componentname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "component", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ComponentVersion> componentversions;

    public Component() {
    }

    public Component(int componenttabid, String componentid, String componentname) {
        this.componenttabid = componenttabid;
        this.componentid = componentid;
        this.componentname = componentname;
    }

    public Component(int componenttabid, String componentid, String componentname,
            List<ComponentVersion> componentversions) {
        this.componenttabid = componenttabid;
        this.componentid = componentid;
        this.componentname = componentname;
        this.componentversions = componentversions;
    }

    //getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is telling you exactly what is wrong. You cannot compare an integer with varchar. PostgreSQL is strict and does not do any magic typecasting for you. I'm guessing SQLServer does typecast automagically (which is a bad thing).

```
    public class ComponentAndVersionCountResponse {

       private Component component;

       private Long versionCount;

       public ComponentAndVersionCountResponse(Component component, Long versionCount) {
           this.component = component;
           this.versionCount = versionCount;
       }

       //getters and setters
```

In this above code snippet, look at your 2nd parameter. You provided it Long and in the query, it accepts only String(i.e. char in terms of database) so either you can replace Long with String type in your method parameter or you can CAST() Long variable into Char in your @Query i.e.

> @Query("SELECT new com.tool.modifiedcomponenttool.payload.response.ComponentAndVersionCountResponse(x, COUNT(CAST(z.componentid)AS text)) FROM Component x JOIN x.componentversions z GROUP By z.componentid")

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue! My statement above was Joining the 2 tables on x.componentid = z.componenttabid, int = string. Instead of x.componentid = z.componentid. Find my updated Query and Response file below.

**ComponentAndVersionCountResponse.java**

```
public class ComponentAndVersionCountResponse {

    private int componenttabid;

    private String componentid;

    private String componentname;

    private Long versionCount;

    public ComponentAndVersionCountResponse() {
    }

    public ComponentAndVersionCountResponse(int componenttabid, String componentid, String componentname,
            Long versionCount) {
        this.componenttabid = componenttabid;
        this.componentid = componentid;
        this.componentname = componentname;
        this.versionCount = versionCount;
    }

//getters and setters
```

**Query**

```
@Query("SELECT new com.tool.modifiedcomponenttool.payload.response.ComponentAndVersionCountResponse(x.componenttabid, x.componentid, x.componentname, COUNT(z.componentid)) FROM Component x INNER JOIN ComponentVersion z ON x.componentid = z.componentid GROUP By x.componenttabid ORDER BY x.componentname")
    public List<ComponentAndVersionCountResponse> findComponentAndVersionCount();
```